# Could not find gradle-7.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2)

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find gradle-7.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.1.2/gradle-7.1.2.jar
> Could not find lint-model-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-model:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-model/30.1.2/lint-model-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find builder-7.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:7.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/7.1.2/builder-7.1.2.jar
> Could not find manifest-merger-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:manifest-merger:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/manifest-merger/30.1.2/manifest-merger-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find sdk-common-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools:sdk-common:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdk-common/30.1.2/sdk-common-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find sdklib-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools:sdklib:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdklib/30.1.2/sdklib-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find repository-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools:repository:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/repository/30.1.2/repository-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find gradle-api-7.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle-api:7.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle-api/7.1.2/gradle-api-7.1.2.jar
> Could not find ddmlib-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/ddms/ddmlib/30.1.2/ddmlib-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find aaptcompiler-7.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:aaptcompiler:7.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aaptcompiler/7.1.2/aaptcompiler-7.1.2.jar
> Could not find bundletool-1.8.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:bundletool:1.8.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/bundletool/1.8.0/bundletool-1.8.0.jar
> Could not find aapt2-proto-7.1.2-7984345.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:7.1.2-7984345).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/7.1.2-7984345/aapt2-proto-7.1.2-7984345.jar
> Could not find databinding-compiler-common-7.1.2.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler-common:7.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-compiler-common/7.1.2/databinding-compiler-common-7.1.2.jar
> Could not find databinding-common-7.1.2.jar (androidx.databinding:databinding-common:7.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/databinding/databinding-common/7.1.2/databinding-common-7.1.2.jar
> Could not find baseLibrary-7.1.2.jar (com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:7.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/7.1.2/baseLibrary-7.1.2.jar
> Could not find layoutlib-api-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.layoutlib:layoutlib-api:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/layoutlib/layoutlib-api/30.1.2/layoutlib-api-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find android-device-provider-ddmlib-proto-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-device-provider-ddmlib-proto:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/utp/android-device-provider-ddmlib-proto/30.1.2/android-device-provider-ddmlib-proto-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find android-device-provider-gradle-proto-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-device-provider-gradle-proto:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/utp/android-device-provider-gradle-proto/30.1.2/android-device-provider-gradle-proto-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find android-test-plugin-host-additional-test-output-proto-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-additional-test-output-proto:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/utp/android-test-plugin-host-additional-test-output-proto/30.1.2/android-test-plugin-host-additional-test-output-proto-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find android-test-plugin-host-coverage-proto-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-coverage-proto:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/utp/android-test-plugin-host-coverage-proto/30.1.2/android-test-plugin-host-coverage-proto-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/utp/android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto/30.1.2/android-test-plugin-host-retention-proto-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.utp:android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/utp/android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto/30.1.2/android-test-plugin-result-listener-gradle-proto-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find builder-model-7.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-model:7.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/7.1.2/builder-model-7.1.2.jar
> Could not find dvlib-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools:dvlib:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/dvlib/30.1.2/dvlib-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find common-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools:common:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/common/30.1.2/common-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find transform-api-2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api.jar (com.android.tools.build:transform-api:2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/transform-api/2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api/transform-api-2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api.jar
> Could not find jetifier-processor-1.0.0-beta09.jar (com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-processor:1.0.0-beta09).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-processor/1.0.0-beta09/jetifier-processor-1.0.0-beta09.jar
> Could not find apkzlib-7.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:apkzlib:7.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apkzlib/7.1.2/apkzlib-7.1.2.jar
> Could not find jetifier-core-1.0.0-beta09.jar (com.android.tools.build.jetifier:jetifier-core:1.0.0-beta09).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/jetifier/jetifier-core/1.0.0-beta09/jetifier-core-1.0.0-beta09.jar
> Could not find protos-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.analytics-library:protos:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/analytics-library/protos/30.1.2/protos-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find signflinger-7.1.2.jar (com.android:signflinger:7.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/signflinger/7.1.2/signflinger-7.1.2.jar
> Could not find zipflinger-7.1.2.jar (com.android:zipflinger:7.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/zipflinger/7.1.2/zipflinger-7.1.2.jar
> Could not find annotations-30.1.2.jar (com.android.tools:annotations:30.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/annotations/30.1.2/annotations-30.1.2.jar
> Could not find apksig-7.1.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:apksig:7.1.2).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/apksig/7.1.2/apksig-7.1.2.jar

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

> not run my project

Answer (score 0):

### Update your Android and Platform SDK and make sure internet is connected properly

[image]

---

If it doesn't helps

Download jar files from [gradle official releases](https://gradle.org/releases/) and paste then into the specified directory

restart your IDE or Code Editor or may be your PC.

It should be working fine (-: